# Can i add a button at every row of report viewer in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, reportviewer

Is there any method to **add button to report viewer at end of each row**. Basically, I want button at every row which has to take content dynamically from database and each button may be identified uniquely through some attribute.

Is there any scenario available for ReportViewer? 
If not so, is there any alternative available for doing such thing in WPF?

Comment: you mean something like [DataGrid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.110).aspx) and [DataGridTemplateColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) ??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a psychic, but I'll try to guess... 
If you data in DataTable and you report in DataGrid then

WPF:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="Column" IsReadOnly="True" Name="f_Grid" SelectionUnit="FullRow">
  <DataGrid.Columns> 
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="name" Binding='{Binding Path=name}'/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="companyName" Binding='{Binding Path=companyName}'/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="phoneNo" Binding='{Binding Path=phoneNo}'/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="officeNo" Binding='{Binding Path=officeNo}'/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="email" Binding='{Binding Path=email}'/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" Header="Id" Binding='{Binding Path=Id}'/>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="auto" Header="ButtonColumn">
      <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <Button Click="ClickEvent" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>        
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

cs:

```
public MyWindow(){
   //initialize window
   MyTable = new DataTable();
   f_Grid.ItemsSource = MyTable.DefaultView;
   //This fill MyTable 
}

protected void ClickEvent(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Button button = sender as Button;
  DataRowView myobject = button.DataContext AS DataRowView;
  if (myobject!=null)
  {
    // you row data in myobject[columnName]
  }
}
```

UPD: Add your column in DataTable

Answer (score 0):

Currently i am using this thing

```
        foreach (Customer cus in db.Customers.ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.name))
        {
            DataRow dr = customer.NewRow();
            dr["name"] = cus.name;
            dr["companyName"] = cus.companyName;
            dr["phoneNo"] = cus.phoneNo;
            dr["officeNo"] = cus.officeNo;
            dr["email"] = cus.email;
            dr["Id"] = cus.Id;

            customer.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

and after polpulating DataTable "customer" i am doing this thing:

_reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", customer));

Comment: See my code. Your **customer** is my **MyTable**. I write solution for **DataGrid**, without **DataSources**. this solution is suitable?